# 'required' is not working for my input tag with form

Tags: html, angular

I'm simply trying to make the fields of my form required so that you can't submit them blank, but I'm having issues. Only my required attribute for 'description' is working as it should. The other fields only highlight red, but don't actually prevent submission.

I've tried placing required in the mat-form-field to no avail and closing the input tags as well.

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Add New Announcement</h1>
<form (submit)="onSubmitAnnouncement(newAnnouncementForm)" #newAnnouncementForm="ngForm">
    <div mat-dialog-content>
        <mat-label for="title">Post Title</mat-label>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input maxlength="55"
            type="text" 
            matInput 
            name="title" 
            id="title" 
            ngModel 
            #title="ngModel"
            required/>
            <mat-error *ngIf="title.invalid">Title is required</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
        <p>Description:</p>
        <mat-form-field>
            <textarea rows="6" cols="50" maxlength="500"
            type="text" 
            matInput 
            name="description" 
            id="description" 
            ngModel 
            #description="ngModel" 
            required>
            <mat-error *ngIf="description.invalid">Description is required</mat-error>
            </textarea>
        </mat-form-field>
        <p>Audience:</p>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Select Audience</mat-label>
            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedAudience" name="aud" required>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let audience of audiences" [value]="audience.value">
                    {{audience.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div mat-dialog-actions>
        <button mat-button type="button" (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
        <button mat-button type="submit" cdkFocusInitial>SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What about check the form status when submitting the form? Like, if (myForm.valid) ...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create your own service (e.g. `validate-form.service`). Then you'd be able to custom check every single input field. This method has always worked for me!